# Pandas concat/merge Dataframes fill missing values with last in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to aggregate the data of two pandas Dataframes into one, where the column `total` needs to backfill with previous existing values, here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-05'],
    'day_count': [1, 1, 1, 1],
    'total': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'],
    'day_count': [2, 2, 2],
    'total': [2, 4, 6]})

# set "date" as index and convert to datetime for later resampling
df1.index = df1['date']
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df2.index = df2['date']
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
```

Now I need to resample both my dataframes to some frequency, let's say `daily` so I would do:

```
df1 = df1.resample('D').agg({'day_count': 'sum', 'total': 'last'})
df2 = df2.resample('D').agg({'day_count': 'sum', 'total': 'last'})
```

The Dataframes now looks like:

```
In [20]: df1
Out[20]:
            day_count  total
date
2020-01-01          1    1.0
2020-01-02          1    2.0
2020-01-03          1    3.0
2020-01-04          0    NaN
2020-01-05          1    4.0


In [22]: df2
Out[22]:
            day_count  total
date
2020-01-02          2      2
2020-01-03          2      4
2020-01-04          2      6
```

Now I need to merge both, but notice that total, has some `NaN` values where I need to backfill the the previously existing value, so I do:

```
df1['total'] = df1['total'].fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
df2['total'] = df2['total'].fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
```

Now df1 looks like:

```
In [25]: df1
Out[25]:
            day_count  total
date
2020-01-01          1      1
2020-01-02          1      2
2020-01-03          1      3
2020-01-04          0      3
2020-01-05          1      4
```

So now I have the two dataframes ready to be merged, I think, so I concat them:

```
final_df = pd.concat([df1, df1]).fillna(method='ffill').groupby(["date"], as_index=True).sum()

In [31]: final_df
Out[31]:
            day_count  total
date
2020-01-01          1      1
2020-01-02          3      4
2020-01-03          3      7
2020-01-04          2      9
2020-01-05          1      4
```

I have the correct aggregation for `day_count` simply summing what's on the same date for both DF's but for `total` I do not get what I expected, which is to get:

```
In [31]: final_df
Out[31]:
            day_count  total
date
2020-01-01          1      1
2020-01-02          3      4
2020-01-03          3      7
2020-01-04          2      9
2020-01-05          1      10  --> this value I miss
```

Certainly I am doing something wrong, I feel like maybe there is even a simpler way to do this, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate them horizontally and groupby along columns:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).ffill().groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```

That said, you can also bypass the individual `fillna` and `groupby`

```
# these are not needed
# df1['total'] = df1['total'].fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
# df2['total'] = df2['total'].fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).ffill().sum(level=0, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
            day_added  total
date                        
2020-01-01        1.0    1.0
2020-01-02        3.0    4.0
2020-01-03        3.0    7.0
2020-01-04        2.0    9.0
2020-01-05        3.0   10.0
```

Comment: Look what you got in `day_added` column, is wrong, for `2020-01-05` you got 3, but it should be 1